# Finding the Levy triplet of a Levy process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

I know the levy triplet of a Poisson process

$N_t$- $(0,0,\lambda\delta_{1}(y))$ and its characteristic function is

$\phi_N=exp[-t\Bigl(\intop_{0}^{\infty}(1-e^{iuy}+iuy1_{\{\mathbf{|}\mathbf{y}|<1\}})\delta_{1}(y)\Big)]$

and also that  of the standard $\alpha$ stable subordinator

$D_t$ - $(\frac{iu\alpha}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)},0,\frac{\alpha}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}y^{-\alpha-1}dy)$  and its characteristic function is

$\phi_{D}(u)=exp[-t\bigl(-\frac{iu\alpha}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}+\intop_{0}^{\infty}(1-e^{iuy}+iuy1_{\{\mathbf{|}\mathbf{y}|<1\}})\frac{\alpha}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}y^{-\alpha-1}dy\bigr)]$

My question is how do I find the triplet of $(N_t,D_t)$ where $N_t$ and $D_t$ are independent?

Since in my case the two processes are independent the Levy measure of $(N_t,D_t)$ should be $v_{x}(dy_{1},dy_{2})=\delta_{1}(y_{1})\frac{\alpha}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}y_{2}^{-\alpha-1}dy_{2}$ (or am I wrong?), in that case the characteristic function should look like this

$exp[-t\Bigl(-iu_{1}-\frac{iu_{2}\alpha}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}+\intop_{\mathbb{R}^{2}/\{0\}}\bigl(1-e^{iu_{1}y_{1}+iu_{2}y_{2}}+iu_{1}y_{1}1_{\{\mathbf{|}\mathbf{y}|<1\}}+iu_{2}y_{2}1_{\{\mathbf{|}\mathbf{y}|<1\}}\bigr)\delta_{1}(y_{1})\frac{\alpha}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}y_{2}^{-\alpha-1}dy_{2}\Bigr)]$

so the Levy triplet should be of the form 
$\bigl((b_1,b_2),0,\delta_{1}(y_{1})\frac{\alpha}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}y_{2}^{-\alpha-1}dy_{2}\bigr)
 $

so my problem boils down to what is the vector $(b_1,b_2)$?

---

I'm not sure I can take the cut-off to be $1_{\{\mathbf{|}\mathbf{y}|<1\}}$ since in that case the integral $\intop_{0}^{\infty}\bigl(1-e^{iu_{1}y_{1}+iu_{2}y_{2}}+iu_{1}y_{1}1_{\{\mathbf{|}\mathbf{y}|<1\}}+iu_{2}y_{2}1_{\{\mathbf{|}\mathbf{y}|<1\}}\bigr)\delta_{1}(y_{1})\frac{\alpha}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}y_{2}^{-\alpha-1}dy_{2}\Bigr)]$ diverges, or can I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the Lévy symbol of a 2-dimensional process $(N,D)$, so your symbol will be a function on $\mathbb R^2$. It will be $\phi_{N,D}(u_1, u_2) = \phi_N(u_1) + \phi_D(u_2)$, by the following trivial argument.

By independence of  $N$ and $D$, the characteristic function of $(N_t, D_t)$ is
$\mathbb E\left[ \exp\left(i (u_1 N_t + u_2 D_t) \right) \right] = \mathbb E \left[ \exp \left( i u_1 N_t \right) \right]  \mathbb E \left[ \exp \left( i u_2 D_t \right) \right] = \exp \left( t \phi_N(u_1) \right) \exp \left( t \phi_D(u_2) \right)$.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I find the Levy triplet of $(N_t,D_t)$ - its Levy measure, drift and Gaussian component(which I know is zero since this is a strictly increasing process)?

Comment: I would try as compensator for the Poisson random measure $\nu(dy) = \delta_0(d y_1) \nu_2(d y_2) + \nu_1(d y_1) \delta_0(d y_2)$. The drift is essentially $b = (b_1, b_2)$, corrected for the changed unit ball ( $1_{\{|y_1| \leq 1\}} 1_{\{|y_2| \leq 1 \}}$ which becomes $1_{\{ ||(y_1, y_2)|| \leq 1 \}}$). Does this work out for you?

Comment: Yes, thank you!!! for some reason I was convinced that Levy measure of the joint process should be $\delta_{0}(y_{1})\frac{\alpha}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}y_{2}^{-\alpha-1}dy_{2}$.